# repeated values not getting inserted in sqlite database

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

In my android application, when i insert repeated values it doesnt show in the database, essentially what i am doing is splitting the srting in 2 halves and inserting one string in one column by insertdata() and second string in second column by insertdata1() and  following is my code

**main**

```
  public  void AddData() {
    btnAddData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                      @Override
                                      public void onClick(View v) {
                                          Spinner dropdown = findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
                                          Spinner dropdown1 = findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
                                          Spinner dropdown2 = findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
                                          Spinner dropdown3 = findViewById(R.id.spinner4);
                                          String join = "-";
                                          String ConcatedString = dropdown.getSelectedItem().toString().concat(join).concat(dropdown1.getSelectedItem().toString());
                                          String ConcatedString1 = dropdown2.getSelectedItem().toString().concat(join).concat(dropdown3.getSelectedItem().toString());
                                          TextView h = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view_id);
                                          h.setText(ConcatedString);
                                          TextView h1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view_id1);
                                          h1.setText(ConcatedString1);



                                          String search = h.getText().toString();

                                              myDb.insertData(h.getText().toString());
                                              myDb.insertData1(h1.getText().toString());
                                              Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"showing"+search,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                      }
                                  }
    );
}
```

**Database helper**

```
public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME + " ( name VARCHAR UNIQUE, name1 VARCHAR UNIQUE)");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}

public void insertData(String name) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_2,name);
    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null ,contentValues);


}

public void insertData1(String name1) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_3,name1);
    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null ,contentValues);


}







public Cursor getAllData() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from " + TABLE_NAME, null);
    return res;
}
```

}

Comment: You've made both columns `UNIQUE`. If that's not what you want, fix your `CREATE TABLE` statement, then clear the database, either by selecting "Clear data" on your app's page in the device Settings, or uninstalling/reinstalling your app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's written in your table description:

> db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME + " ( name VARCHAR **UNIQUE**,
>   name1 VARCHAR **UNIQUE**)");

Your two columns are uniques, so they don't accept repeated values. You should remove UNIQUE for those two columns and add a ID column wich will be auto generated.

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, name VARCHAR, name1 VARCHAR)");
```

You 've got an error in your insert methods. You can't insert into COL_1 or COL_3 because they are not your columns names. You should write this =>

In your first method =>

```
contentValues.put("name",name);
```

In your second method =>

```
contentValues.put("name1",name1);
```

And why don't you write only one method to insert data ? This way you should have only one line in your database. But maybe that's what you want ? I would write this method :

```
public void insertData(String name, String name1) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("name",name);
    contentValues.put("name1",name1);
    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null ,contentValues);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Database helper class modify onCreate method. Remove UNIQUE in name & name1. if your column is UNIQUE, you can't insert same value twice. Create a ID column to give a primary key and auto increment ID. code should be like below.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME + " ( ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT, name1 TEXT)");
}
```